# ios8 blur effect disappear

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiblureffect

Thanks for reading my question
I had some trouble stabilizing the intensity of blur effect

I had a UIImageView with blur effect (Extralight) which covered the whole view as a background
The intensity of the blur effect looked just fine
But after I added items onto the storyboard
the blur effect dimmed so much almost disappear

sorry i don't have enough reputation to upload pictures

anyone know what caused it, and how to solve?

Thank you very much!

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {                  
    // set bg image and blur         
    bg.image = UIImage(named: "my portrait")         
    var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style:      UIBlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight)         
    var blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect:     blurEffect)         
    blurView.frame = bg.bounds                  
    bg.addSubview(blurView) 
}
```

Comment: Posting some code samples would be helpful.

Comment: @bgilham I posted some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the reason
It is because the blur view is added under function ViewDidLayoutSubview
So the blur is added multiple times
That's the reason it's looks dimmer and dimmer